# How to do multiplication in third dimension in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I want to do this multiplication between the LP 2x2 matrix and the H 2x1 vector.

```
LP = @(theta) [cos(theta) .^ 2, sin(theta) .* cos(theta); sin(theta) .* cos(theta), sin(theta) .^ 2];
H = [1; 0];
LP(theta) * H
```

If I pass theta as a scalar (e.g. 0 or pi) everything works. But, I want to pass a vector of theta to plot the results.
When I do `LP(0:0.01:2*pi) * H` things start to break obtaining a 2x(2*100) instead of 2x1x100.

```
figure();
hold on;
filtering = LP(0:0.01:2*pi) * H;
plot(0:0.01:2*pi, filtering(1,:)); % x
plot(0:0.01:2*pi, filtering(2,:)); % y
```

My question is, there is a way that I can build my equation in matrix form avoiding loops?

Comment: `LP(scalar)` returns a 2x2 matrix, but `LP(vector)` returns a size `[2 2*length(vector)]` matrix. You can also use a column vector or even a 2D matrix as input (e.g. `LP(ones(2))`). The result is a tiling of 2x2 times the input size. That is how the function was defined, right?

Comment: Yes, and this prevents me to do LP(vector) * H.

Comment: I think should exist a way to keep the syntax as `LP(vector) * H` and make it work as intended generating a 2x(vector length) output matrix.

Comment: The problem is that 3D matrix multiplications are not defined in matlab. AFAIK it's best to reshape the inputs yourself before and after, so that Matlab does the fast internal stuff as defined. Something like this? `lena=7; a=reshape(LP(ones(1,lena)),[lena*2 2]); b=repmat([1;0],lena,1); a'*b`

Comment: There is an error in your question, a `2x2` matrix can not be multiplied by a `1x2` matrix, and if the second matrix is a `2x1` matrix then it will result in a `2x1` matrix not a `2x2` one. So we can not help you for the moment.

Comment: @obchardon Just for size comparison, this actually works 

    temp = LP(0) * H;
    2x2 * 1x2 = 2x1

Comment: In your code `H` is a `2x1` matrix not a `1x2` one, but in your description your define `H` as a `1x2` matrix. And no a `2x2 * 1x2` does not produce a `2x1` matrix.

Comment: Now, I see what you mean!
I've plotted the sizes, actually, I have:
2x2 * 2x1 = 2x1

Answer (score 1):

```
theta = 0:0.01:2*pi; % your vector of angles
LPcell = arrayfun(LP,theta,'uni',false); % cell array of 2D matrices
LP3 = cat(3,LPcell{:}); % 3D array made of 2D pages
result = pagemtimes(LP3,H); % 3D matrix multiply with the 2D pages
```

If you have an older version of MATLAB that doesn't have the pagemtimes( ) function, you could download similar functions from the FEX to do the 3D matrix multiply (e.g., mmx, mtimesx, multiprod)

Alternatively, instead of doing the arrayfun( ) stuff above to generate the 3D array you could rewrite your LP function handle as a vectorized version to get the 3D array you want from the outset.